# Validate ajax, if data is not exist disable submit button

Tags: php, ajax

i have autocompletion ajax, and i want to implement if the data is not exist then the submit button will become disabled and the button enabled if the data is exist and successfully inputed to the form.

how to achieve that? im really new to ajax

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function validate(){
          var id = $("#id").val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'get',
              url: 'ajax.php',
              data:"id="+id ,
          }).success(function (data) {
              var json = data,
              obj = JSON.parse(json);
              $('#nama').val(obj.nama);
              $('#golongan').val(obj.golongan);
              $('#divisi').val(obj.divisi);
          });
      }
    </script>
```

form

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="id">ID karyawan</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" onkeyup="validate()" aria-describedby="id" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nama">Nama Karyawan</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control readonly" name="nama" id="nama" readonly required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="golongan">Golongan</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="golongan" id="golongan" readonly required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="divisi">Divisi</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="divisi" id="divisi" readonly required>
            </div>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
include_once "config.php";

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT user.id,user.nama,user.divisi,user.golongan 
                                 FROM user
                                 WHERE id='$id'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$data = array(
            'nama'=>$result['nama'],
            'golongan'=>$result['golongan'],
            'divisi'=>$result['divisi'],);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

the code above is auto completion by id from the database, if the id is registered then the form is filled automatically while the form other than id have `readonly` textarea element

thanks before, appreciate any help

Comment: From where are you calling `validate()` ? Which "data" you want to check?

Comment: the validate is from the form `<input type="number" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" onkeyup="validate()" aria-describedby="id" required>`

Comment: if `$id` is wrong u get empty result??? how to u solve???

Comment: @Ashok in the end im using php to force user cant submiting the form if the input id is not available at database

Comment: i dont understand what u asking?? is php or javascript, Please ask clear with code

Comment: and where is the `submit` button in html

Comment: i updated Answer `input` field set default`disabled`

Comment: @Ashok its at the bottom of the form

Comment: set `input ` default `<input //** code *//  disabled >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax.php

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,nama,divisi,golongan FROM user WHERE id = ? ");
$query->bind_param("i", $id);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_array();
if(count($row)) 
{
    $data = array(
                'nama'=>$row['nama'],
                'golongan'=>$row['golongan'],
                'divisi'=>$row['divisi'],
                );
}else{
    $data = array(
                'nama'=> 'error'
                );
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Ajax Req

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate(){
      var id = $("#id").val();
      $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data:"id="+id ,
      }).success(function (data) {
          var json = data,
          obj = JSON.parse(json);
          if(obj['nama'] !== "error"){
              $('#nama').val(obj['nama']);
              $('#golongan').val(obj['golongan']);
              $('#divisi').val(obj['divisi']);
              // default disabled this input after success input enabled 
              $( "#input_id" ).prop( "disabled", false );
          }
      });
  }
</script>
```